# Wireless over ear headphones

Tags: headphones

I had purchased Bluedio headphones, but they turned out to be rather useless.  They

- are usually noisy (scratchy)
- don't pair reliably, I am left 10-20 minutes at the start of the meetings trying to get them working.

My plug in ones work fine every time, so the hardware on my PC is ok.

I am looking for over ear wireless (BLE), chargeable headphones

- I use them for online meetings only,
- NOT for gaming, and NOT for listening to music
- Price point about $200 (Sony ones are $500 around here!!).
- For Windows 10 PC and Windows 11 laptop
- I dont want in the ear or on the ear ones as I have hearing aids and glasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying a [Sony WHC720NB](https://electronics.sony.com/audio/headphones/headband/p/whch720n-b), over ear headphones. It was a balance between cost and clarity/battery life.

[image]

##### Blurb from their site

> - Sony’s lightest Wireless Noise-canceling headband ever.
> - Take noise canceling to the next level with Sony’s Integrated Processor V1, so you can fully immerse yourself in the music.
> - Super comfortable and lightweight design.
> - Adjustable Ambient Sound mode and Adaptive Sound control features tailors sound to suit the environment around you.
> - Up to 35-hour battery life with quick charging (3 min charge for up to 1 hour of playback).
> - High sound quality and well-balanced sound tuning.
> - Crystal clear hands-free calling and voice assistant with Precise Voice Pickup technology.
> - Multipoint connection allows you to quickly switch between two devices at once.
> - Boost the quality of compressed music files and enjoy streaming music with high quality sound through DSEE™.
> - Build-in microphone

---

##### Usage Feedback

After using them, I made a good choice.  The sound is a little hissy only if I turn on the Noise Cancelling.  I don't need NC anyway, I prefer to hear things around me as well.  They are miles better than what I had before.

They also pair seamlessly with my Samsung TV.  Once paired, if I turn on the headphones close to the TV, the TV pops up a question and asks if I want to use the headphones.  I click on Yes and it streams to teh headphones.  When I switch off teh headphones, the TV goes back to using its speker.

Answer (score 1):

I bought the [Sony Mk3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XQRY8SB) and [Bose 700](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BV3CXJLR), and ended up returning the Sony. Both were very similar and had excellent noise canceling. They came out with the [Mk4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08C7KG5LP) shortly thereafter that had all the features that I chose the Bose for.

I have been using my Bose 700 5 days a week for 2 years and the battery life has dropped from 21 hours to 16 hours per charge. I have had to replace the ear cups twice, but otherwise they look brand new despite what I have put them through.